# Which web server is used by Heroku for Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Which web server does a Node.js application use when it is deployed on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you.

Heroku's [sample Node.js application](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started) uses [Express](https://expressjs.com/):

- The application [depends on `express`](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/97e6c72491c7531507bfc5413903e0e00e31e1b0/package.json#L15)
- The `index.js` script [instantiates](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/97e6c72491c7531507bfc5413903e0e00e31e1b0/index.js#L1) Express and then [listens](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/97e6c72491c7531507bfc5413903e0e00e31e1b0/index.js#L10) on the [port given by the `PORT` environment variable](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/97e6c72491c7531507bfc5413903e0e00e31e1b0/index.js#L3)
- The `Procfile` [specifies that web dynos should run `node index.js`](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/97e6c72491c7531507bfc5413903e0e00e31e1b0/Procfile#L1) (though if the `Procfile` doesn't specify a `web` command [Heroku defaults to your application's `start` script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script))

In my experience this would be a common choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your Node.js application is the web server that runs, but Heroku uses Amazon Web Services (AWS) to host your web server.

Comment: I mean to say that whether Heroku uses any web server software to run my Nodejs application